# Como llamar una variable que esta en otro metodo

Tags: java

Buenas noches necesito llamar la variable en otro metodo mas que todo la que suma los numeros binarios, que seria resultadoSuma, como la puedo utilizar en otro metodo.

```
    public static void agregarNumeroUnoBinario(){

    a.ingresarNumeroBinario(Integer.parseInt(binarioNumeroUno));
    a.ingresarNumeroBinario(Integer.parseInt(binarioNumeroDos));

    int resultadoSuma = Integer.parseInt(binarioNumeroUno) + Integer.parseInt(binarioNumeroDos);

    b.ingresarNumerosBinarios(resultadoSuma);

}
```

Comment: Saludos. (Conozco muy poco de java). Te puedo comentar que para ello la variable que requieres debe estar al alcance de tus métodos; pero como son `static` (al menos el que muestras) deberás pasarlo por referencia u otra opción es que en vez de `void` sea `int` lo que devuelva tu métodos (es decir *convertirlo* en función).

Comment: Una variable definida en un metodo solo existe en ese metodo no puede ser referenciada desde otro. Lo que se puede hacer es regresar su valor usando return o definirla en un ámbito desde donde sea alcanzable por otros métodos. Para que la vea otro método estático tendrías que declararla en la clase como estatica. Técnicamente hablando. En términos de diseño  es cuestionable.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es una función para que realize y devuelva siempre la suma.
De esta manera siempre que quieras sumar algo solo invocas tu función y le pasas dos argumentos de tipo entero y listo.

```java
  public static void agregarNumeroUnoBinario(){
    a.ingresarNumeroBinario(Integer.parseInt(binarioNumeroUno));
    a.ingresarNumeroBinario(Integer.parseInt(binarioNumeroDos));
    
    // invocas tu funcion sumar() y le pasas como argumentos
    //los numeros que queres sumar y valor devuelto
    // por esta funcion va a ser asignado a resultadoSuma
    int resultadoSuma = sumar(binarioNumeroUno, binarioNumeroDos);    
    // int resultadoSuma = Integer.parseInt(binarioNumeroUno) + Integer.parseInt(binarioNumeroDos);

    b.ingresarNumerosBinarios(resultadoSuma);
  }
  
  public static int sumar(int numeroUno, int numeroDos){
    int resultadoSuma = numeroUno + numeroDos //realiza suma
    return resultadoSuma; //devuelve la suma
  }
```

Ah un consejito como norma general (rule of thumb) fijate en el [Principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica) (single-responsibility principle (SRP))

Asi tu código te va a ser más fácil de mantener, de leer, de debugging, etc.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias me funciono

Comment: Que bueno! feliz de ayudar!

Answer (score 0):

Compañero, podrías hacer que el método devuelva el valor de la variable que desees con **return**:

```
public static int agregarNumeroUnoBinario(){

a.ingresarNumeroBinario(Integer.parseInt(binarioNumeroUno));
a.ingresarNumeroBinario(Integer.parseInt(binarioNumeroDos));

int resultadoSuma = Integer.parseInt(binarioNumeroUno) + Integer.parseInt(binarioNumeroDos);

b.ingresarNumerosBinarios(resultadoSuma);

return resultadoSuma;
}
```

**Otra opción** que se me ocurre, **si ambos métodos pertenecen a la misma clase** y haces que no sean estáticos, podría ser declarar la variable resultadoSuma directamente en la clase, de esa forma cualquier método podrá acceder a ella directamente.

Espero haberte podido ayudar :)